# How to return javascript code to be executed by client in Jersey Rest?

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

What I am trying to do is that after executing the following REST API the Browser should alert the "Hello World!!" string in the browser.

I thought annotating the function with @Produces("text/javascript") will take care of it. But as I am hitting the resource at the following url

```
    http://localhost:8080/JAXRS-HelloWorld/rest/script/helloWorld
```

JAXRS-HelloWorld is the name of the App and I have specified the url as /rest*

I am getting everything as String. Not as executable Javascript code.

```
  package com.bablo.rest;

  import javax.ws.rs.GET;
  import javax.ws.rs.Path;
  import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
  import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
  @Path("script")

 public class JavaScriptTesting {
  @GET
  @Produces("text/javascript")
  @Path("/helloWorld")
  public Response helloWorld(){
        String responseParam = "alert(Hello World!!)";
        return Response.ok(responseParam).build();
    } 
}
```

How to get the Browser to execute the alert function? Can we achieve this just by doing some trick in the Server Side REST API?

Comment: Embed it in an html page with the alert function called in the onLoad handler. And return that html page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the server to execute client-side javascript. This is not going to work.

You need to update your REST client so that the javascript code returned by the server is evaluated:

```
 var response = callRestApi();
 eval(response);
```

Or you can return HTML code that embed your script, so that it is evaluated by the browser:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces(value = MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String test() {
        return "<script>alert('test');</script>";
    }
```

Comment: Which line are you talking about ?

Comment: @cghislai Is n't there any way to achieve this using the rest annontations or by doing something in my server side REST API.

Answer (score 0):

We use the Command pattern and the window.call() function to execute commands.

The commands need to match the JavaScript methods that you want to execute (that's why the toString() is overridden)

```
public enum Commands {
  LOAD_BLOCK,

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    String[] parts = name().split("_");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // loop through all parts of the name
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
      String word = parts[i];
      // use a lowercase letter for the first word
      if (i == 0) {
        sb.append(word.toLowerCase());
      // follow camel case pattern (first letter capital)
      } else {
        sb.append(String.valueOf(word.charAt(0)));
        sb.append(word.substring(1, word.length()).toLowerCase());
      }
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

Build and send commands to the Client from the Rest resource

```
Command load = new Command(Commands.LOAD_BLOCK.toString(), new String[]{"b1"})
return Response.status(200).entity(load).build();
```

In the JavaScript file prepare a method that calls this Rest resource and run a method such as below that takees a list of commands as input and excutes them with the provided argments.

```
function triggerEvents(commands){
    for (var index = 0; index < commands.length; index++){
        var command = commands[index];
        console.debug("executing " + command.function);
        await window[command.function].call(null, command.arguments);
    }
}
```

It will look for a matching function and execute with the given parameters if found

```
async function loadBlock(blockId) {
  // do some work
}
```